# How to trigger a function when uib model is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, mean-stack

I have a uib model for which I want to trigger a function when it is closed.

My template,

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="xpertdox-ad-model.html">
<div class="modal-header"></div>
</script>
```

My code,

```
   $('#xpertdox-ad-model.html').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (){
    alert('Model is closed');
   });
```

But this is not getting triggered.Can any one please suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: Upon further inspection of your code, I have a few questions for you.  Why do you need to apply an ID to a `<script>` tag?  What is the close event called in the API, are you certain it is called `hidden.bs.modal`?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you may want to remedy across your `HTML` is getting rid of dots "." in the id attribute.  If that would be too cumbersome, you can use a more reliable jQuery selector for when dots are used.  Using the standard hashtag `$('#some_id')` id selector will break when dots are in your id.

```
var modal_header_selector = $('div[id="xpertdox-ad-model.html"]');

modal_header_selector.on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    alert('Model is closed');
    console.log('The modal has been closed.');
});
```

Comment: @Duster if you press F12 in your browser, and navigate to the console tab, what error is it giving you?